# Building an array in Javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, highcharts

**Well, turns out camp_amount wasn't setup properly and returned "NaN"... Thanks anyway! You guys made me look past the array syntax, which turns out to be fine. Sometimes I just get a bit lost in code.**

For use with highcharts I have the following array:

```
dashboardData = [[tableData[1], parseFloat(tableData[12])],[tableData[14], parseFloat(tableData[25])]];
```

I can literally just paste that as highcharts series data:

```
data: dashboardData
```

However, I need to build the array in a for loop because the length of the array will vary. So I need to build an array that ends up with the same structure as above, which would be something like:

```
0: Array[2]
0: "a string"
1: 312

1: Array[2]
0: "another string"
1: 1668
```

How do I build this up? I tried the following but it doesn't work...

```
var dashboardData = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= camp_amount.length; i++) {
    dashboardData.push([tableData[i], tableData[i + 1]]);
}
```

Comment: if that didnt work. there should be something in your firebug console to check when you run it.

Comment: What's in 'camp_amount' and what's the relation to 'tableData' since you are using its as one array

Comment: camp_amount is the amount of campaigns found, it then runs through the tableData to fetch the name and a value (users) per campaign. Is the manner I build up the array correct in your opinion? Because that would help a lot already: to know it's not a syntax error.

Comment: So, is issue resolved? :)

Comment: @PawełFus: It appears to be...  This should be closed or removed by the author.